# How to edit script to run on all files within directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg, shell-script, bash-scripting

How to make this script run on all video files within directory executed?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fade OUT, TO BLACK:

# length of the fade out
fade_duration=2 # seconds

if [[ ! $2 ]]; then
    cat<<EOF
Usage:
    ${0##*/} <input mp4> <output mp4>
EOF
    exit 1
fi

for x in bc awk ffprobe ffmpeg; do
    if ! type &>/dev/null $x; then
        echo >&2 "$x should be installed"
        ((err++))
    fi
done

((err > 0)) && exit 1

duration=$(ffprobe -select_streams v -show_streams "$1" 2>/dev/null |
    awk -F= '$1 == "duration"{print $2}')
final_cut=$(bc -l <<< "$duration - $fade_duration")
ffmpeg -i "$1" \
    -filter:v "fade=out:st=$final_cut:d=$fade_duration" \
    -af "afade=t=out:st=$final_cut:d=$fade_duration" \
    -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -strict -2 "$2"
```

Currently, the above script works as follows:

```
./script.sh input output
```

The following code runs on all files within directory, but the above script does not:

```
# Fade IN, FROM BLACK:
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:v 'fade=in:0:50' -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a copy faded/"${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

I would like to learn how to make the script run on all files within directory, and also combine the above code so that the script also does "Fade IN" and not just "Fade OUT".

Comment: That's asking for too much to overcome my laziness, but I can tell you that you can eliminate `awk` by just using `ffprobe` alone: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 "$1"`. Also, get rid of `-strict -2`: people copy and paste that without knowing what it does and it isn't needed unless you are trying to encode AAC audio with ancient ffmpeg.

Comment: I am not experienced enough to know what you are talking about. However I got the first sentence and laughed :).

Comment: `for i in *.mp4; do ./script.sh "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done` — no? Also, fading in and out at the same time is easy, just add `fade=in`in your filter, e.g. `fade=in,fade=out`.